# Verify that all objects of the class that extends RealmObject are empty

Tags: java, android, realm

my Book.class that extends realmobject.

```
public class Book extends RealmObject {
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

how do I find out if these objects are empty someone help me

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? And what "objects" are you talking about?

Comment: I want to know if it still exists in the database objects of my Book class I tried so 'public boolean hasBook() {
        return !realm.allObjects(Book.class).isEmpty();
    }' but did not work

Comment: For that, you'd need a `@PrimaryKey` annotated field, and use `realm.where(Book.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst() != null`.

Comment: Thank your suggestion was useful for me!